# How to get boolean output from an event handler

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom-events

I'm trying to check if a 'tr' element has a nextSilbing element, using a 'DOMNodeInserted' event that will detect a DOM change whenever a tr element was added into a table element after it's inserted through a form like below:

[image]

I tried to get a boolean output from the event handler but I didn't succeed, so I tried to create a function to get that output but this was impossible unless I wrapped the statement with a console.log:

```
function findIdx(el) {
  console.log(document.querySelector('tr:first-of-type').nextSibling === null);
}
$('tbody').on('DOMNodeInserted', function(e) {
  let a = $(e.target)
  findIdx(a);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can cast any value to boolean type with the use of **!!**

```js
const anyValidValue = 1;

console.log('valiud: ', !!anyValidValue);

const notValidValue = null;

console.log('not valiud: ', !!notValidValue);
```

so I belive your function can look like this:

```
function findIdx(el) {
  return !!document.querySelector('tr:first-of-type').nextSibling;
}
```

Comment: the event handler still not generate any output, even with that